# I encountered issues in exporting business objects sdk

Tags: business-objects

What is the best way of exporting an business objects webi document to excel without going to infoview and scheduling the web i document

Answer (score 0):

Yes... There is a way.

Use **Web Intelligence Rich Client**. You can save the report as MS Excel or PDF.